# how to assign the mosquitto_sub output to a variable using php exec?

Tags: php, mosquitto

in my publisher, I tried something like

```
$msg = '{"test":"a","test2":"b"}';
$publishCommand = "mosquitto_pub -h IP_ADDRESS_HERE -t TOPIC_HERE -m $msg";
exec($publishCommand);
```

that snippet above works.

because when I tried manually in the server this snippet below, i can see the json string output

```
mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t TOPIC_HERE -i 'ID_HERE'
```

however when I tried using that snippet above in PHP, in order for me to assign the output to a variable and be able to json_decode the data, it doesn't work at all, I cannot get the output with this snippet below

```
exec("mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t TOPIC_HERE -i 'ID_HERE'", $output);
print_r($output);
```

NOR with this one

```
exec("mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t TOPIC_HERE -i 'ID_HERE' 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

NOR with this one

```
exec("/usr/bin/mosquitto_sub -h 127.0.0.1 -t TOPIC_HERE -i 'ID_HERE'", $output);
print_r($output);
```

I also tried using the passthru OR system , but both of this are immediately displaying the output and I am not able to assign the output to a variable
even after using ob_* series of functions e.g ob_start, ob_get_contents and etc...

Comment: Why are you not using a PHP mosquitto client rather than execing the mosquitto_sub command line client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is most likely because `mosquitto_sub` will never exit.

By default `mosquitto_sub` runs for ever printing out every message that it published to a matching topic. In order to get the output you need `mosquitto_sub` to return and close it's handle on stdout.

`mosquitto_sub` can be told how many messages to wait for before it exits with the `-C` option. From the man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html):

> **-C**
>
> Disconnect and exit the program immediately after the given count of
>   messages have been received. This may be useful in shell scripts where
>   on a single status value is required, for example.

If you want to subscribe to MQTT topics from PHP I suggest you have look at a native PHP client. There is a list [here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/libraries#php)